# Automount to root

Tags: automount

Aside from naming hosts badly and causing root directtory conflicts, is there any reason that the /etc/auto.master file can't contain

```
/    -hosts
```

to automount host directories at the root level?

So if I have defined hosts prod01, prod02,... then doing

```
ls /prod02/jobs
```

will automount the /jobs directory of prod02 at the root level.

Answer (score 2):

The automounter has complete control of directories you configure it to use, so you would lose *all* local directories if you did that.

Comment: +1 to geekosaur, that would be  problem.  However I do think that's how old nfs-based diskless clients used to work, right?

Comment: Correct, but they also had to mount `/` specially in the kernel.